# Cannot display database data in AngularJS project via MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I followed code  at https://phpcmsforce.wordpress.com/ but I cannot seem to make the data display.
Please tell me if I am missing something!

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

<html ng-app=”rjtApp”>

<head>BLAH </head>

<body ng-controller=”projectsController”>
<div ng-include src=”Project.html”></div>

</body> </html>
```

Project.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<body>
<table ng-controller=”projectsController”>

    <thead><tr><th>Title</th><th>App Type</th><th>Code</th><th>Type</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr ng-repeat="project in projects">
        <td>{{project.title}}</td>
        <td>{{project.type}}</td>
        <td>{{project.pcode}}</td>
        <td> <div ng-if="project.proj_type = 'Internal'"> <span class='label label-primary'>{{project.proj_type}}</span> </div> <div ng-if="project.proj_type = 'External'"> <span class='label label-info'>{{project.proj_type}}</span> </div> </td>

    </tr>
    </tbody> </table>
```

app.js:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('rjtApp' []);

app.controller('projectsController', function ($scope, $http)
{
 getProject();
 function getProject() {
$http.post("getProject.php").success(function(data)) {
  $scope.projects = data;
  });
 };
}
```

config.php:

```
<?php

define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_NAME', 'project');
?>
```

getProject.php:

```
<?php
require_once'config.php';

$query="select * from tbl_projects";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error,__LINE__);
$arr=array(); if($result->num_rows>0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
}
echo $json_response = json_encode($arr);
?>
```

It is just displaying {{project.title}}, etc. on the Project.html browser.
And when I display index.html, nothing shows up
I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: if it shows unrendered angular template tags then try to open the browsers dev tools and se if you get any errors logged to the console.

Comment: why do you have all these things in project.html?
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
its already there in index.html

<body>`